# 5000+ CoreData Queries maxing out iPhone CPU and lagging the display

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

An App I'm developing pulls down a product catalogue (will be approx 40,000 products) via an API and parses them into CoreData so they can be easily searched through.

I have this method to handle the parsing of the data, downloading it works perfectly and as intended. I have a download progress bar and a processing progress bar. The download one works as required, but the label (or progress bar) doesn't change to the processing text or percentage progress. I've checked programmatically and it does output the correct label text to the console, it just doesn't show in the view.

Having checked using the activity monitor, the phone is maxing out CPU wise.. so I'm guessing that's why none of the on-view changes are being shown. Is there anyway I can reduce the computational load and get it showing the progress bar properly? I'm sure this is far from efficient code anyway, I haven't quite go to the stage where I know best practices etc..

**Modified to use loop GCD**

I've changed the code to make use of GCD, however this is giving me an error when run though: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x8b26720> was mutated while being enumerated.'

```
- (void) processUpdatesBG {

    NSArray *jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *products = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"products"];

    NSInteger productDBCount = _productDBCount;
    productDBCount = 0;

    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;
    _managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;

    self.totalCount = [products count];

    for (id product in products) {

        dispatch_queue_t processTheUpdates = dispatch_queue_create("com.app.process_the_updates", 0);



            NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Products" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];
            [request setIncludesSubentities:NO];


            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"codes == %@", [product valueForKey:@"product_codes"]];
            [request setPredicate:predicate];



         dispatch_async(processTheUpdates,  ^{
             NSError *err;
             NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];
            if (results.count == 0){
                // Product doesn't exist with code, make a new product

                NSLog(@"Product.. %@", [product valueForKey:@"product_name"]);

                NSManagedObject* newProduct;
                newProduct = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Products" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

                [newProduct setValue:[product valueForKey:@"product_name"] forKey:@"name"];
                [newProduct setValue:[product valueForKey:@"product_codes"] forKey:@"codes"];

                if ([product valueForKey:@"information"] == (id)[NSNull null]){
                    // No information, NULL
                    [newProduct setValue:@"" forKey:@"information"];
                } else {
                    NSString *information = [product valueForKey:@"information"];
                    [newProduct setValue:information forKey:@"information"];

                }

            } else {

                // Product exists, update existing product
                for (NSManagedObject *r in results) {
                    [r setValue:[product valueForKey:@"product_name"] forKey:@"name"];

                    if ([product valueForKey:@"information"] == (id)[NSNull null]){
                        // No information, NULL
                        [r setValue:@"" forKey:@"information"];
                    } else {
                        NSString *information = [product valueForKey:@"information"];
                        [r setValue:information forKey:@"information"];
                    }

                }


            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.productDBCount = productDBCount + 1;
                NSNumber *progress = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(self.productDBCount / self.totalCount)];
                self.downloadUpdateProgress.progress = [progress floatValue];
                NSLog(@"Added product");
            });

        });



    }

    NSError *error;

    if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Database Updated");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Database not Updated, Error: %@", error);
    }


    self.updateStatus.text = @"Update Completed!";
    self.downloadUpdateProgress.hidden = YES;
    self.close.hidden = NO;

    //    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    //    NSString *currentTimestamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    //    NSLog(@"%@", currentTimestamp);


    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *apiUpdateTimestamp = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"last_updated"];
    [prefs setObject:now forKey:@"last_downloaded_update"];
    [prefs setObject:apiUpdateTimestamp forKey:@"api_update_timestamp"];
    [prefs synchronize];
    // Set the lastDownloadedTimestamp as today
    // Set the last

}
```

**Original Code**

```
- (void) processUpdates {
    self.updateStatus.text = @"Processing Updates";
    self.downloadUpdateProgress.progress = 0;

    NSArray *jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *products = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"products"];

    NSInteger productDBCount = 0; 

    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;
    _managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;

    NSInteger totalCount = [products count];

    for (id product in products) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Products" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];
        [request setIncludesSubentities:NO];
        NSError *err;
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"codes == %@", [product valueForKey:@"product_codes"]];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];

        NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];

        if (results.count == 0){
        // Product doesn't exist with code, make a new product

            NSManagedObject* newProduct;
            newProduct = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Products" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

            [newProduct setValue:[product valueForKey:@"product_name"] forKey:@"name"];
            [newProduct setValue:[product valueForKey:@"product_codes"] forKey:@"codes"];

            if ([product valueForKey:@"information"] == (id)[NSNull null]){
                // No information, NULL
                [newProduct setValue:@"" forKey:@"information"];
            } else {
                NSString *information = [product valueForKey:@"information"];
                [newProduct setValue:information forKey:@"information"];

            }                  

        } else {

            // Product exists, update existing product
            for (NSManagedObject *r in results) {
                [r setValue:[product valueForKey:@"product_name"] forKey:@"name"];

                if ([product valueForKey:@"information"] == (id)[NSNull null]){
                    // No information, NULL
                    [r setValue:@"" forKey:@"information"];
                } else {
                    NSString *information = [product valueForKey:@"information"];
                    [r setValue:information forKey:@"information"];                    
                }

            }

        }

        productDBCount = productDBCount + 1;
        NSNumber *progress = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(productDBCount / totalCount)];
        self.downloadUpdateProgress.progress = [progress floatValue];

    }

    NSError *error;

    if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Database Updated");        
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Database not Updated, Error: %@", error);
    }


    self.updateStatus.text = @"Update Completed!";
    self.downloadUpdateProgress.hidden = YES;
    self.close.hidden = NO;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSString *currentTimestamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    NSLog(@"%@", currentTimestamp);


    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *apiUpdateTimestamp = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"last_updated"];
    [prefs setObject:currentTimestamp forKey:@"last_downloaded_update"];
    [prefs setObject:apiUpdateTimestamp forKey:@"api_update_timestamp"];
    [prefs synchronize];
    // Set the lastDownloadedTimestamp as today
    // Set the last

}
```

Comment: Well for the performance part you should really do any intensive tasks on the background (take a look at [GCD & NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091)). Now for the `CoreData` part, I think that [this technique](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html) will help you.

Comment: Be aware that there are a few caveats.  CoreData has performWithBlock: methods which facilitate multithreading.  However while the API became available in iOS 5.1, it only actually works in iOS 6+.  GCD is the safe, all-purpose solution.  Also be aware that NSManagedObjectContexts are NOT thread-safe.  You need to instantiate a new one on each thread, each hooked the main persistant store.  And you need to handle merging contexts after a save with the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't heard of that. This application isn't going to be catering for iOS5, only iOS6+ so it could be applicable. I fixed the mutation error by instantiating the product ID within the GCD call itself which performing the looping and outputting to the log which I required. However, the code within dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ isn't executing. 

I'll look into declaring the NSManagedObjectContexts each time, as well as the merging. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be running on multiple threads to free up the main thread for UI work. Sadly, Core Data on multiple threads is not trivial. This link demonstrates a wonderful way of implementing this http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Answer (score 1):

You can try dooing your fetch activity in background.

```
dispatch_queue_t <your dispatch>;//do it in .m before @implementation
```

then

```
<your dispatch>=dispatch_queue_create("name", nil);//create your dispatch
```

then code in

```
dispatch_async(myDispatch_photosView, ^{<your code>});
```

this will prevent your view from lagging

Comment: This sounds like an interesting way of dealing with it. How would this work from a looping through products point of view? Would I just put the creation of the product object in the queue or would you need to put the entire loop in the queue?

Comment: i usually dispatch_async(myDispatch_photosView, ^{<your code>}); this inside the loop so the loop executes on main thread but is not effected by the iteration i have used it for lazy loadin of images

Comment: I've given it a go, in a few different configurations, but it's giving me an error when run through. I'd edited my original post to contain the new code.

Comment: @HeftyHijacker you are trying to change products or some other collection while dooing fast enumeration.

Comment: This is parsing through an array of data and either updating products or adding products, depending on whether they exist or not. So looping through each product, checking and performing the relevant change.

Comment: use for loop with i=0 to i<arry.count insted of fast enumeration and do let me know

Answer (score 0):

I went with something like this. I couldn't find an example that worked, so hopefully this will help someone in the future. Very basic, but you should be able to get the jist. This is the solution I opted for in the end.

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundDispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

for (id p in products) {

  // Dispatch the following code on our background queue
  dispatch_async(backgroundDispatchQueue,
    ^{
        id product = p;
        // Because at this point we are running in another thread we need to create a
        // new NSManagedContext using the app's persistance store coordinator

        NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundThreadContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
        [backgroundThreadContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];

        /*
        *
        *
        * Perform fetch and other actions as required.
        *
        *
        */

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {

            self.productDBCount = self.productDBCount + 1;
            float progress = ((float)self.productDBCount / (float)self.totalCount);
            int percent = progress * 100.0f;
            self.downloadUpdateProgress.progress = progress;
            self.percentageComplete.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", percent];

        });

      });
}
```